# Why does python's ThreadPoolExecutor work queue appear to accept more items than its maximum workers?

Tags: python, multithreading, executor

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class Sandbox:
    def __init__(self, n=5):
        self.n = n
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(n)

    def make_request(self):
        if self.executor._work_queue.qsize() < self.n:
            self.executor.submit(self.do_something_that_takes_long)
            print('HTTP_202')
        else:
            print('HTTP_429')

    def do_something_that_takes_long(self):
        time.sleep(10)


def do_ok_situation():
    s = Sandbox()
    for _ in range(5):
        s.make_request()


def do_bad_situation():
    s = Sandbox()
    for _ in range(100):
        s.make_request()


# do_ok_situation()
do_bad_situation()
```

This will output

```
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_202
HTTP_429
HTTP_429
HTTP_429
HTTP_429
...
```

This code will output 10 HTTP_200's (on my machine) instead 5. I expected that number of requests I make to the executor is equal to the number of jobs put into the thread executor queue.

Why is this the case? How can I limit this number to the number of max workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `self.executor._work_queue.qsize()` returns the number of requests that are sitting in the `work_queue` waiting for a thread to execute them.  However when you call `submit()` there is often an idle thread in the thread pool that is immediately available to handle the request, so for the first five calls to `make_request()`, the request doesn't go into the `work_queue` at all, but rather gets handed directly to a thread to execute.

You can demonstrate this behavior to yourself by adding a line like

```
print("qSize=%i"%self.executor._work_queue.qsize())
```

to the front of your `make_request()` method; you'll see that `qSize` remains 0 for the first 5 calls, and only starts growing larger after all 5 threads in the ThreadPool are already busy executing `something_that_takes_long` and therefore the additional requests go into the queue instead.